# How would I get it to choose a random number out of 1 and 2 in Python?

Tags: python, random

So the 'player' has to enter a number either 1 or 2. I need to use Python to make it so it will randomly choose a number so one will be 'good' and the player lives and the other 'bad' so the player dies.

Comment: Oh it's python sorry should have said

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to choose randomly between two values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55399338/how-to-choose-randomly-between-two-values)

Answer (score 0):

```
import random

c = random.choice([1, 2])
```

or

```
c = random.randrange(1, 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is something that you could have Googled or consulted the documentation for... however, here's a basic implementation.

```
import random
x = random.randint(1, 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import random
variable_name = random.randint(x, y)
# x is the min and y is the max
```

Comment: is there any need for the trailing comma at the end of the argument list? it is confusing...

Comment: Sorry, didn't mean to put that there, there is no need for that comma, I will fix it