# How to choose randomly between two values?

Tags: python, numpy

So basically I'm trying to get a piece of code to randomly choose between two values -40 and 40.

To do so, I was thinking of using good old mathematics like -

random_num = ((-1)^value)*40, where value = {1, 2}.

random_num, as the name suggest should be a random number.

Any help ?

I am using python, solution using libraries is acceptable.

Comment: So `np.random.randint(-40,40, size)`?

Comment: `import random
random.randint(-40,40)` did you try this already?

Comment: I'll try it thx (sorry if the answer is easy for you but I'm not familiar with python at all)

Comment: @yatu and Justice_Lords "answers" are not correct. Op wants to have either -40 or 40, not a random number between -40 and 40.

Comment: Is your question "how do I get a random value between -40 and 40", "how do I get a random value of either -40 or 40" or "how do I get a random value of either 1 or 2"?

Comment: You want values in *range* -40 to 40 or to *choose* -40 or 40?

Comment: @Guybrush `"choose between values -40 and 40"`......

Comment: @yatu Looks ambiguous to me

Comment: then just `np.random.choice([-40,40])`

Comment: Why do so many programmers add the NumPy overhead when the standard library provides a perfect solution?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If you want a random integer values between -40 and +40, then

```
import random
random.randint(-40, 40)
```

https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/random.html#random.randint

If you want to choose either -40 or +40, then

```
 import random
 random.choice([-40, 40])
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice

If you really prefer to go with your implementation of choosing either 1 or 2, as in your question, then plug in those values in random.choice method.

Provided the above solutions, since I feel there is some ambiguity in the question.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming that `L` is a list of values you want to choose from, then `random.choice(L)` will do the job.

In your case:

```
import random
L = [-40, 40]
print(random.choice(L))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `choices` function in python to achieve this. If you want values to be chosen to be only -40 or 40, the second argument is the probability/weights.

```
from random import choices
choices([-40,40], [0.5,0.5])
```

Comment: OP wants either -40 or 40, not a value between -40 and 40.

Comment: @Guybrush Updated my answer. This should be fine

Comment: I don't think ``choices`` should be preferred to ``choice`` here, because the former returns a list of selected items (even if there is only one item). That means that OP will have to do ``x = choices(...)[0]`` where ``x = choice(...)`` is enough, simpler and more readable ;-)

Comment: Agreed @Guybrush!