# Function that chooses between two values? [Groovy][Jenkins]

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-groovy

What I want to do:
I have a variable that needs to be assigned a value that changes every time the method is called. Every time the code runs the it cycles between two values, either string1 or string2.
This would be a function that is part of a Groovy script for a Jenkins pipeline: first time around the variable will be assigned to string1, second time string2, third time string1 again and so on and so forth.
I have tried this snippet but using Random it repeats the string, I just want it to cycle between the two values.
Python has a choice property for random to restrict the choices, cannot find one in groovy.
[How to choose randomly between two values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55399338/how-to-choose-randomly-between-two-values)

```
def test = ""
def string1or2(test) {
    test = ["string", "string2"]
    assert test instanceof List
    def rand = test.sort {Math.random()}
    println(rand[0])
    return(rand[0])
}
string1or2(test)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import groovy.transform.Field

@Field
def index = 0
@Field
def options = ['string1', 'string2']

def string1or2() {
    return options[(index++) % options.size()]
}

// print 10 values
10.times { println string1or2() }
```